# How to produce sharp images

Tags: javascript, python, image, opencv, image-processing

Is it possible to produce a sharp image from a set of images. I found this article: https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/ where it is aligning multiple images to produce a sharper image. I have tried this approach but the image produced is not as desired. The images and the aligned image can be seen from this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=177U_B574E1Fi2AF-zxJ6GSHG7cw_2krV
Is there a way to produce better results than the one provided in the article. I have looked at how photoshop does focus stacking. Is there a way to replicate its approach in python.

Comment: use highboost filtering to sharp the image http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gradient/node2.html https://theailearner.com/2019/05/14/unsharp-masking-and-highboost-filtering/

Comment: Is the referred article for a set of images or just one image? I went through the article and it discusses about sharpening of one image only. What I wanted was to use the given set of images and produce a sharpened image using the each individual image.

Comment: The reference you linked was aligning channels. Each channel was sharp, but misaligned so that it did not look clear. That process is not for sharpening images, if each image is already sharp, but not quite aligned. So I think you have made a bad assumption. You have lots of blurry images. So that method will not sharpen them. You need to do deconvolution to correct out of focus images. The deconvolution will depend upon the cause of the blurriness -- motion blur, defocus or some other issue. Look into blind deconvolution.

Comment: You could have a look at enfuse utility for creating focus stacks. http://enblend.sourceforge.net/enfuse.doc/enfuse_4.2.xhtml/enfuse.html#sec%3Afocus-stacks--depth-of-field-increase
Any remaining softness may be due to the softness in the original images.